# What's the easiest way to have "settings profiles" in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

Scrapy picks up settings from settings.py (there are default settings, project settings, per-spider settings as well). What I'm looking for is being able to have more than one file with settings and being able to switch between them as I launch my spiders quickly. If there is some inheritance between files that would be awesome too.

If you know Spring Boot from Java world there is an idea of profile. You have application.settings file with your base settings. And then you can have application-dev.settings and application-prod.settings. If you run your application with option -Dspring.profiles.active=dev then it will pick up application.settings and add application-dev.settings on top of it. This way you can maintain multiple configurations in parallel and rapidly switch between them.

I've found an approach for Scrapy with no supporting code required. The approach is to use SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE and import base settings file in my dev and prod modules. Are there any other approaches that you use?

Launch line in my case would look like:

```
export SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectname.profiles.dev && scrapy crawl myspider
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, if you're only going to change one or two values, then it would be simpler to use a single dynamic `settings.py` (as mentioned in [Gallaecio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159665/4082726)).

However, if you really need separate settings, there is an even shorter way by defining separate "projects" in `scrapy.cfg` ([docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#sharing-the-root-directory-between-projects)):

```
[settings]
default = myproject.settings.dev
dev = myproject.settings.dev
prod = myproject.settings.prod
```

Then to run a specific one:

```
SCRAPY_PROJECT=prod scrapy crawl myspider
SCRAPY_PROJECT=dev scrapy crawl myspider
```

If you don't specify `SCRAPY_PROJECT` it will use `default`.

---

And yes, you can inherit from settings files. Replace your `settings.py` file with a module instead:

```
myproject/settings/__init__.py
myproject/settings/base.py
myproject/settings/dev.py
myproject/settings/prod.py
```

In `base.py` you can have exactly what you have in `settings.py`. Then at the top of each override file you add:

```
from .base import *

# Override settings in the same way as if they were declared in settings.py
```

That wildcard import is usually a bad practice, but in this case since it's just a plain Python file so the end result is just having all the variables available. This is a trick we often use in Django ([example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html)).

Comment: Very nice answer! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` is the best approach.

Alternatively, since a settings module is a Python script, you could change settings dynamically from within `settings.py`. I’ve seen this done, for example, to detect automatically whether a spider is running in a local machine or on a Scrapyd server, and adjust the settings accordingly at run time.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a good idea I didn't think about.